# PackageKit logs a message about "only_trusted:0"

Tags: security, logs, packagekit

I ran `pkcon update force`.  I noticed PackageKit is logging about `only_trusted:0`.  That is, an operation where the `only_trusted` option is disabled.  Even though I did not pass `--allow-untrusted` to `pkcon`.

`PackageKit[19819]: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)`

So PackageKit is writing a log message about allowing untrusted packages.  I did not want it to do that.  I did not ask it do that.  Why is it logging this message?  Is there a problem in PackageKit?

```
$ sudo systemctl status packagekit.service
● packagekit.service - PackageKit Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/packagekit.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-04-08 12:34:58 BST; 1min 29s ago
 Main PID: 19819 (packagekitd)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 192.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/packagekit.service
           └─19819 /usr/libexec/packagekitd

Apr 08 12:34:58 alan-laptop PackageKit[19819]: daemon start
Apr 08 12:34:58 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Apr 08 12:34:58 alan-laptop systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Apr 08 12:34:58 alan-laptop PackageKit[19819]: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
Apr 08 12:34:58 alan-laptop PackageKit[19819]: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Apr 08 12:35:09 alan-laptop PackageKit[19819]: refresh-cache transaction /17652_eabaebee from uid 1000 finished with success after 11018ms

$ rpm -q PackageKit
PackageKit-1.1.12-2.fc29.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--allow-untrusted` option, and the `only_trusted` flag, are not relevant when refreshing.

They are only relevant when you request that a package be installed or upgraded (or removed, possibly?).

On the client side:

- `pk-console.c` always checks whether the `pkcon` command is run with `--allow_untrusted`, and sets the `only_trusted` property of `pk_task` accordingly.  However:
- `pk_task_refresh_cache_async()` ignores the `pk_task` property, and unconditionally sets  `PK_TRANSACTION_FLAG_ENUM_ONLY_TRUSTED` in `PkTaskState::transaction_flags`.
- This then calls `pk_task_do_async_action()`.  But that function does not actually use `PkTaskState::transaction_flags` for anything, if `PkTaskState::role` is `PK_ROLE_ENUM_REFRESH_CACHE`.

On the dnf backend side:

- The only place that checks for `PK_TRANSACTION_FLAG_ENUM_ONLY_TRUSTED` in `PkBackendDnfJobData::transaction_flags`, is `pk_backend_transaction_run()`.
- `pk_backend_transaction_run()` is not called from `pk_backend_refresh_cache_thread()`.  It is only relevant for jobs which install or remove packages.  For example, it is called from `pk_backend_install_packages_thread()`.